# Get JPEGSnoop output to a text box

Tags: c#, process, output, standards

Is there any way to get JPEGsnoop output data (ex. huffman tables) into a text box in real time? I need to get the jpegsnoop output image data in real time into a text box using Process.

Can anyone tell me is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could invoke JPEGsnoop command-line mode via Process (output to temp file) and then read that into your program? The command-line mode will generate an output file that contains the huffman codes and all other major JFIF markers.

-- developer of JPEGsnoop

Comment: need to specify what you want and what you have done